# Xcode 6, main storyboard, colors off

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, xcode6

The colors on the main storyboard doesn't correspond to what the simulator is rendering. How come?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, check that you didn't change neither the alpha of any view nor superview, or the colors in code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://inaka.net/blog/2014/09/05/getting-the-right-colors-in-your-ios-app/) you can find a interesting explanation, but here are the basics:

1. You need to use the Digital Color Meter, with the option "Display in sRGB".
2. Pick the desired color from your design.
3. Apply the RGB values given by Digital Color Meter in the Interface Builder by previously choosing Generic RGB profile on the gear icon.